# Propagation of Uncertainty vs Dividing Uncertainties

Tags: experimental-physics, mathematics, statistics

I have a quick question!

When I’m calculating the uncertainty of a formula, like $v = d/t$ . . . What method do I use? Sticking with my example ($v = d/t$).

Do I convert the uncertainties of distance and time into their relative Uncertainties and add them up?

Or do I use one of the propagation of uncertainty formulas (see image below)?

I did both methods, but I received different results, albeit only a fraction or so off. I just want to be kosher and precise in my calculations.

Thank you for your help!

[image]

[image: my work]

Comment: Can you show us the steps that lead to different answers, and explain what you mean by "a fraction or so off"?

Comment: The link is broken for me.  It's not a good idea to post links on this site.  It's not uncommon for links that work eventually break.   Please post your work using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  It's not hard to learn.

Comment: The answer by Jeffrey should answer your question.  I will emphasize his statement that the linear method should be avoided.  Note that in the special cases of $z=xy$ and $z=x/y$ the "correct" expression reduces to $(\sigma_z/z)^2 = (\sigma_x/x)^2 + (\sigma_y/y)^2$ which might be easier to deal with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a variable $U$ that depends on parameters $X_j$. We want the uncertainty (error) in $U$ expressed as $\Delta U$ as a function of the errors (uncertainties) in $X_j$ expressed as $\Delta X_j$.

The simplest approach is to sum relative uncertainties.

$$ \frac{\Delta U}{U} = \sum \frac{\Delta X_j}{X_j} $$

This is a rough, worse than first order approximation that has no basis in first principles. This approach should generally be avoided without at least an appreciation of how it arises in the next method.

The next level of analysis is to account for the functional form of $U = f(X_1, X_2 \ldots X_N)$. This adds a term that might be called the sensitivity factor $S_j$ as

$$ S_j \equiv \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial X_j}\right)_{X_k \neq X_j} $$

Using this term, we write an improved first order approximation as:

$$ \Delta U = \sum |S_j| \Delta X_j $$

The equivalence of this equation to the expression for a total derivative $dU = \sum S_j dX$ is not without coincidence. The absolute function is required so that all errors add regardless of the sign of the partial derivative $S_j$. Finally, for a simple multiplication or division expression such as $U = XY$ or $U = X/Y$, we can prove that this expression becomes the same as the sum of relative uncertainties (the first expression).

The above expression is not uncommon and indeed is not incorrect to use as a first order approximation. It will provide an upper bounds to the uncertainty $\Delta U$. It is however not the fundamentally correct expression to use to propagate uncertainties in a rigorous manner.

The fundamentally correct approach to propagate uncertainties in a rigorous manner is to use the equation for the linear propagation of uncertainties.

$$ \Delta^2 U = \sum S^2_j \Delta^2 X_j $$

This first principles expression basically states that we are adding the variances of the measurement distributions weighted by their contributing sensitivities. This is only exact when the uncertainties $\Delta X_j$ are uncorrelated. When the uncertainties in the terms are correlated, a more sophisticated approach is required.

The expression is called "linear" propagation because it sums the weighted variances. The variance of a random distribution of measurements is the square of the standard deviation of the distribution.

The basic first order approach and the linear propagation approach will not give the same result, although with rounding they may appear the same. The first order approximation as a summation of relative uncertainties gives an upper bounds.

A thorough discussion of both approaches is given in the book [Introduction to Error Analysis from Taylor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/093570275X). Examples are provided for different case studies. See also [this link on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty).

Comment: My interpretation of the original post is that the OP is asking to choose between the formula posted, and the linear combination of relative uncertainty, ie. $\sigma_z/z = \sigma_x/x + \sigma_y/y$.  This is what the OP seems to be suggesting, but I'm not sure.  Is that what you mean by "linear"?    Note that both the OP and this answer could benefit from a clearer presentation, including some math.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So . . . When would I ever use the linear method? Was it just introduced in text books to help give better insight into the first principle expression (the formula)?

Comment: @Riss The linear propagation method is the first principle approach when uncertainties are uncorrelated. I refer to the book from Taylor as a reference for details. I also suggest Measurements and Their Uncertainties by Hughes and Hase. Otherwise, I do not entirely understand your question.

Comment: @JeffreyJWeimer I think the issue I’m having here is the terminology. Linear is when I simply add my uncertainties or fractional uncertainties, right? This method, as clarified above, is not as precise/accurate as the quadratic formula (the equation I posted) typically used. So my question is . . . what was the point in introducing this linear method when I wouldn’t be using it for my calculations anyways? Was the linear method just a stepping stone towards understanding the quadratic formula used? Or does the linear method have its applications at certain times?

Comment: @Riss You may sum absolute or relative uncertainties linearly. That is however NOT what we mean when we state linear propagation of uncertainties. The point of introducing a simple sum of uncertainties expression is because it is easy to apply and because it always will give the upper bounds to the uncertainty. I refer to Taylor for a fuller development to explain both equations (the simple sum of uncertainties form and the formal linear propagation of uncertainties form) along these lines--a valid estimate of the upper bounds and a correct treatment of variances.